# Open Matlab .m Files

Tags: matlab, default-programs

I am running Matlab 2021b with Ubuntu 20.04.3. I would like to be able to doubleclick .m files so that they automatically open in Matlab. The main problem is that right clicking the file -> Properties -> Open With doesn't show Matlab as an application.

Comment: If your details are correct (20.04.3), then you've not applied security updates & software patches since very early 2022, so I suggest you apply them asap & try again. I'll also suggest keeping your system offline (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release of 20.04.4, but installed systems upgraded **before** that ISO release date)

Comment: Thanks.  Any advice about my question?